# use blobfuse inside an Azure Kubernetes (AKS) container

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, fuse

We wanted to configure blobfuse inside an Azure Kubernetes container to access the Azure storage service.

I created the storage account and a blob container.
I [installed blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) on the docker image (I tried with alpine and with ubuntu:22.04 images).

I start my application through a Jenkins pipeline with this configuration:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: my_ubuntu:20.04
    command: ['cat']
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
    devices:
      - /dev/fuse      
"""
    }
  }
```

I ran this command inside my docker container:

```
blobfuse /path/to/my/buckett --container-name=${AZURE_BLOB_CONTAINER} --tmp-path=/tmp/path --log-level=LOG_DEBUG --basic-remount-check=true
```

I got

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

Running `modprobe fuse` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1068-azure`

All answers I googled mentioned using --privileged and /dev/fuse device, which I did, with no results.

The same procedure works fine on my linux desktop, but not from inside a docker container on the AKS cluster.

Is this even the right approach to access the Azure Storage service from inside Kubernetes?

Is it possible to fix the error `fuse: device not found` ?

Answer (score 0):

> `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`

I have also researched regarding fuse issues:

- Either the fuse kernel module isn't loaded on your host computer (very unlikely)
- Either the container you're using to perform the build doesn't have enough privileages.

`--privileged` gives too many permissions to the container instead of you should be able to get things working by replacing it with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN` like below.

```
docker run -d --rm \
           --device /dev/fuse \
           --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
      <image_id/name>
```

and also run

```
docker run -d --rm \
           --device /dev/fuse \
           --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
           --security-opt apparmor:unconfined \
      <image_id/name>
```

Try to run this command if it fails try to check up setup and check with versions and also blobfuse [installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux#install-blobfuse-on-linux)

For reference I also suggest you this ***Article***

- [Mounting Azure Files and Blobs using Non-traditional options in Kubernetes - by Arun Kumar Singh](https://medium.com/codex/mounting-azure-files-and-blobs-using-non-traditional-options-in-kubernetes-e12b1522f14f)
- [kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver: Azure Blob Storage CSI driver (github.com)](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver)